# Exclusion from PhD in Economics selection in Italy for degree

Tags: phd

I received an exclusion email from Italian University for PhD in Management program due to not eligbility.

I earned 4-year bachelor's degree (Vietnam) and one-year second level master diploma (Italy) => Total 5 years of studying

The requirements are: bachelor (3 year for Italian system) plus Master of Science (2 years) => Total 5 years of studying

My question is: how to solve my current problem for next year in order to meet their requirements:

Solution 1: take a 2-year master and wait next 3 years for applying
Solution 2: take some extensive courses which they provide credit/certificate.

Anyone has been in my situation? Could you give me some advice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a very specific question and the answer may even depend on the particular university and how they interpret the rules.

I suggest you approach the secretary that is responsible for graduate admissions, and ask him/her directly whether you need the 2-year master's program or are there other options.